# Clean Keset Hasofer Online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, safrus

I have been trying to learn R' Ganzfried's Sefer Keset haSofer, however, I have been unable to find a printed copy and the HebrewBooks.org copy I've found is nearly illegible.

Is there an online copy of this particular sefer which is easily legible, perhaps an e-text version or newer scan?

Comment: Is [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49253&st=&pgnum=41) any cleaner than what you were using before?

Comment: @Shokhet, that's what I was using

Comment: Aha. That was the cleanest version I found on HB. Good luck!

Comment: When I would need a she'elah to ascertain the identity of a printed letter, I know it's a lost cause.

Comment: [אין בוויקיטקסט העברי דף בשם "קסת הסופר"י](http://he.wikisource.org/w/index.php?search=%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8&title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93%3A%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9&go=%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A3) :(

Comment: You might try asking [הפורום המרכזי לסופרי סת"ם](http://www.or-lasofer.com/%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%96%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%9D.html) (the central forum for sofrei stam)

Comment: There is Mishnas Hasofer which is comprehensive : https://merkazstam.com/product/mishnas-hasofer-mwnt-hsvpr/

Comment: This is solely in English, not sure if that helps http://www.hasoferet.com/halakha-for-scribes/keset-ha-sofer/

Comment: I would recommend buying this sefer from Mizrachi Books. It contains a few seforim on Stam which you may find useful plus it contains the Keset HaSofer. https://www.ebay.com/itm/Hebrew-COLLECTION-OF-SEFARIM-ON-STA-M-Safrut/391992383727?hash=item5b449118ef:g:6zgAAOSwdXtamYJh:sc:USPSMedia!11580!US!-1 http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=391992383727&category=171243&pm=1&ds=0&t=1522271869000&ver=0&cspheader=1&oversion=e7140676

Comment: @sam, I own the burgundy edition, which is somewhat more complete than the blue edition. The print of the Keset in this edition is awful, but my other print copies are clear

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but it seems to be online now at Sefaria [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Keset_HaSofer?lang=bi).

Comment: That only has the first few sections

Comment: @DoubleAA, a source of frequent consternation, but this is still the best answer this question has received in nearly 4 1/2 years